# Typescript conditional types with type guard

Tags: typescript

I have this code and I am having trouble in the conditional types problem.
I am trying to infer if an object that was received as a function's argument is from a specific type and if it does I wish that its arguments type will be influenced by it.

For example with my code:

```
type Relation = "and" | "or";

type CertainType = { key: unknown };

export type InputType = CertainType["key"] | Array<CertainType["key"]>;

interface InputOptions<T extends InputType> {
  inputKey: T;
  relation: T extends Array<CertainType["key"]> ? Relation : never;
}

function isOptionsAreArrayOptions(
  options: InputType
): options is InputOptions<Array<CertainType["key"]>> {
  if (Array.isArray(options) && options.length > 1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function someFunc<T extends InputType>(options: InputOptions<T>): boolean {
  if (isOptionsAreArrayOptions(options)) {
    // Options is now InputOptions<Array<CertainType["key"]>> (array).

    /* ---THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CHECK---. */
    options.relation = 'and';

    if (options.relation === "and") {
      // Some code...
      return true;
      // in the else it has to be the "or".
    } else {
      // Some code...
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    // relation has to be never becasuse options is InputOptions<CertainType["key"]>;
    // Do something...
    return false;
  }
}
```

I with that after the typeguard usage in the `someFunc` function the options.relation will be assignable to the values "or" | "and" and in the else section it will be `never`.

Currently this is the error message I get:
`Type '"and"' is not assignable to type '(T extends Array<CertainType["key"]> ? Relation : never) & Relation'.`

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-n7k6wo

Comment: Missing definition for `flagOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was with this type:

```
interface InputOptions<T extends InputType> {
  inputKey: T;
  relation: T extends Array<CertainType["key"]> ? Relation : never;
}
```

Which allowed different types that can extend InputType to be optional answers and not limit the results to the one that the union type type (InputType) has.

I changed it to this type:

```
type InputOptions<T> =
    T extends Array<CertainType["key"]> ?
    {inputKey: T, relation: Relation } :
    T extends CertainType["key"] ? {inputKey: T} : never;
```

A similar, workable answer could also be achieved by converting this type into a union type of the explicit options:

```
type A = {inputKey: Array<CertainType["key"]>, relation: Relation};
type B = {inputKey: CertainType["key"]};
type InputOptions = A | B;
```

In my opinion I rather the implicit solution (the first one) since the explicit subtypes doesn't have any important meaning.

Comment: You don't need to use type aliases for the second, though?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with options: Relation as an options type.

```
function someFunc<T extends InputType>(options: Relation): boolean {
...
}
```

Comment: I have needs from the other options values (inputKey).